# conflict between dat.gui.js and trackballControl.js in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

When using three.js, I found a conflict between `dat.gui.js` and `trackballControl.js`. For example, after changing values by dat.gui, I can't rotate the camera with mousemove because the mouse can not move out from the area of GUI. Why and how to deal with it?

[image]

Comment: It will be a conflict of the mouse event listeners. Post code of how you are adding the three.js scene and the dat.gui to your page so we can help you

Comment: You are right.It is  a conflict of the mouse event listeners. So I replace trackballControl.js with OrbitControls.js, and write the touch event into OrbitControls.js.It is on my github (https://github.com/ljt1469/threejs). If you have some other good ideas, contact me. Thamk you!

Comment: There should be no need to rewrite anything, These controller classes have been used for years and are pretty robust. You need to send a dom element as the second argument to the TranckballControls constructor. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The [trackballControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js) constructor allows for a second argument of a dom element.
This dom element is what the mouse event listeners for the controls will be added to. If you don't supply this argument, the mouse event listeners will be added to the `document` (which I believe is your problem).

It is hard to give you an example which will work for you, because you have not posted your code.
You should be able to send the renderer dom element to the trackballControls to fix your problem.
eg.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
// send dom element to trackballControlls.
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```

Run snippet below for working example.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, material, controls, gui, directionalLight;
init();
render();
animate();

function init() {
    // Renderer.
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    //renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add renderer to page
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Create camera.
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 400;
    
    // Add TrackballControls, sending dom element to attach mouseevent listeners to.
    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

    // Create scene.
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Create material
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

    // Create cube and add to scene.
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    // Create ambient light and add to scene.
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); // soft white light
    scene.add(light);

    // Create directional light and add to scene.
    directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    // Add listener for window resize.
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
    
    // Add GUI
    var gui = new dat.GUI();
    var lightFolder = gui.addFolder('Light');
    lightFolder.add(directionalLight, 'intensity').onChange(function(){render()});
    lightFolder.open();
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
}

// Only called by controls change or gui change.
function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    controls.handleResize();
}
```

```css
body {
margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dataarts/dat.gui/v0.6.2/build/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are right. I added the second argument of a dom element as your said. The problem is solved.Thank you!